# Не работает обработчик прерываний в FASM

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Я хочу написать код с использованием своего обработчика прерываний таймера в FASM.
Вот упрощённый код того, что у меня получилось:

```
org 100h
mov word [es:(8*4)], timer_handler
sti

Main:
jmp Main

timer_handler:
pushf
pusha
  mov dx, msg
  mov ah, $09
  int 21h
popa
popf
iret

msg db 'Hello world!$'
```

Я предполагаю, что 18 раз в секунду у меня выведется сообщение, но ничего не происходит. Только начал пробывать использовать свои обработчики прерываний, но ничего не выходит.
Может дело в том что я не по тому адресу засылаю свой обработчик в таблицу прерываний?

Comment: В таблицу векторов нужно помещать дальние `FAR` адреса обработчиков, т.е. в формате `сегмент:смещение`, а вы указываете только смещение. Запишите туда текущее значение регистра `CS`. Но если в целом, то ваш пример это не обработчик, а какая-то пародия на него. Есть свои правила перехвата аппаратных прерываний, которые вы не учитываете. Например всегда возвращать управление оригин.обработчику, и т.д.

Comment: Но ведь я не менял значение es, а это означает, что он совпадает со значением cs. Всё таки хотел бы разобраться с этим вопросом, было бы замечательно если бы вы посоветовали какие-нибудь источники для этого.

Comment: Вообще тема интересная. Помню как я бодался с играми за Int8 и Int9, не все из них отдавали управление обратно, а некоторые норовили перехватить прерывания повторно на каждый чих

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Всё таки хотел бы разобраться с этим вопросом

При создании своих обработчиков, нужно придерживаться основного правила - всегда возвращать управление оригин.обработчику. При работе с таймером это особо критично, т.к. его может использовать не только сама ОС, но и чипсет мат.платы (учитывая, что это прерывание биос, а не дос). Работу с таблицой векторов прерываний IVT (Interrupt Vector Table) лучше доверить спец.функциям сервиса MS-DOS: `AH=35h` читает оригин.вектор из IVT в регистры `ES:BX`, а `AH=25h` записывает в IVT адрес нового обработчика из пары `DS:DX`.

Непосредственно свой обработчик можно оформить двумя способами:

1. Дать отработать оригин.обработчику, после чего принять от него управление. Это наиболее правильный способ перехвата прерываний.
2. Перехватить управление первым, после чего обязательно возвратить бразды оригин.обработчику.

В случае перехвата системного таймера, длительность работы нашего обработчика не должна превышать одного тика, т.е. `18/60=0,3 сек`. Иначе вся система начнёт тормозить, и может даже зависнуть. Вектор(08h) таймера который вы перехватываете в своём примере, по цепочке возвращает управление в `int-1Ch`. Поэтому когда программам требуется таймер, то в доках по MS-DOS советуют перехватывать именно вектор(1Ch), не трогая при этом `int-08h`.

В примере ниже именно такой алгоритм. Здесь, приняв управление, наш обработчик сразу возвращает его по оригин.вектору. Когда системный отработает, то своей инструкцией `IRET` сам возвратит нам руль (не тестировалось, могут быть ошибки):

```
;// fasm-code
;//--------------
org 100h
jmp Initialize

oldHandler  dw 0,0  ;// под оригин.вектор

Initialize:
push es                   ;// AH=35h портит регистр ES
mov  ax,351Ch             ;// AH = функция, AL = вектор
int  21h                  ;// копируем оригин.вектор из IVT.
mov  [oldHandler],bx      ;// BX = смещение
mov  [oldHandler+2],es    ;// ES = сегмент оригин.обработчика
pop  es

mov  ax,251Ch             ;// AH=25h записывает новый вектор в IVT
mov  dx,newHandler        ;// DS:DX = указатель на наш обработчик 
int  21h  

align 16                  ;// выравнить наш обработчик на границу параграфа памяти
newHandler:
pushf                     ;// имитация инструкции INT
call dword[oldHandler]    ;// сразу возвращаем управление оригин.обработчику!

call @f                   ;// после IRET оригин.обработчика попадаем сюда..
db   'Hello World!$'      ;// строка для вывода
@@:
pop  dx                   ;// DX = адрес строки
mov  ah,9                 ;// AH = печать
int  21h

mov  ah,0Bh    ;// проверить буфер клавиатуры
int  21h       ;// 
or   al,al     ;// если была нажата любая клавиша,
jnz  @exit     ;// то на выход!
iret           ;// иначе, конец обработчика.

@exit:
mov  ax,251Ch           ;// восстановить оригин.вектор в IVT
mov  dx,[oldHandler]    ;// DS:DX = сохранённый вектор
mov  bx,[oldHandler+2]
mov  ds,bx
int  21h
int  20h
```

Почитать по теме: Зубков - "Ассемблер для Windows, DOS, Linux" (глава 5.8.1)
https://lshoshia.science.tsu.ge/assembler.pdf